# How does v8 scoping work?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

This question can be narrowed down to:

- What's the difference between `Handle`, `Persistent` and `Local`?
- How to properly dispose of each?
- When dealing with `Local`s, how *exactly* to work with `HandleScope` in cases where, for instance, I don't have any return values? (I've only seen examples where `scope.Close(value)` is returned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `HandleScope`s as a stack -- each time you create one, it's the newest scope.  As they go out of scope, any `Local<>` created after that HandleScope can be deleted/GC'd.

`Persistent<>` is untouched by `HandleScope` and should only be removed with `Dispose`.

If you are returning a value from a function, you create that as a `Local` and then, call `scope.Close(myLocalObject)` which passes ownership of that object from the created scope to the parent scope.  Functions not returning anything still must return an undefined e.g. `scope.Close(Undefined());`

*edit*

`Handle` is just the base class for `Local` and `Persistent`.  There's good information on scoping and handles on the v8 developer site: https://developers.google.com/v8/embed

Re: returning `args.this`, that's used in a constructor function (e.g. `new MyObject`) if you look in the comments in the example code on that page.

Comment: The question get 4 upvotes, are you an expert on this? give me some good and bad examples to understand v8 scope.

Comment: I am left with two questions: 1. What about `Handle`? 2. I was looking at some example code for Node addons, and if you go down a little from http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects, you'll see at some point there's a `return args.This();` even though we have a `HandleScope`. What would happen here?

Comment: My understanding is that `Handle` is just an abstract class/interface.

Comment: Added a few notes inline.

Comment: What I meant by the question was "why don't we `return scope.Close(args.This())` or something of the like if we have a `HandleScope` around?"

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you other than "in a constructor, that's what you do."

Comment: `As they go out of scope` what does this means, do handle scope are automtically discraded when they are removed from C++ stack (Say created in a function call, and when that function is executed the handleScope created in it is automitically discarded) ?